# How to encode an INFO+LIST subchunk according to RIFF and defacto standards?

Tags: wav, riff

I'm trying to correctly encode a `LIST` chunk of the `INFO` type such that it follows standards. The original 1.0 IBM/Microsoft spec for RIFF (https://www.aelius.com/njh/wavemetatools/doc/riffmci.pdf) is confusing me.

The spec says:

> The chunks listed below may only appear in an `INFO` list. Each chunk contains a `ZSTR`, or null-terminated text string.

...and then it lists a table of sub-chunks, e.g. `IARL`, `IART`, and so on.

If I take the spec statement as "each chunk *only* contains a `ZSTR`", then there wouldn't be sub-chunk IDs encoded. On the decoding side, there'd be no way to identify what each text was meant to convey, e.g. `IART` for artist.

So that can't be right. If I instead interpret the statement as "use the standard chunk header we defined earlier in our spec followed by a `ZSTR`", then that means an 8-byte header with `chunk ID` and `chunk data size` followed by a null-terminated string. That might be right, but it seems redundant, and I've definitely seen implementations of wave encoding that don't use this. Still, I figure this is *probably* the right interpretation.

A third way I've seen that seems optimal is `ChunkID` + `ZSTR`. But it may not be standard.

Is there a spec-supported way that is correct? Or if specification truly is ambiguous, is there a defacto standard (very popular way of doing it)?